# How can I get a slice from an Option in Rust?

Tags: rust, slice

I have an `Option` in Rust, and I need to use it in a function that accepts a slice. How do I get a slice from an `Option` where `Some(x)`'s slice has one element and `None`'s has zero elements?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### Rust 1.75 and later

`Option` now has [`as_slice`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.as_slice) and [`as_mut_slice`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.as_mut_slice) methods in the standard library.

### Prior to Rust 1.75

This will produce an immutable slice of an `Option`:

```rust
the_option.as_ref()
    .map(core::slice::from_ref)
    .unwrap_or_default()
```

This will produce a mutable slice of an `Option`:

```rust
the_mutable_option.as_mut()
    .map(core::slice::from_mut)
    .unwrap_or_default()
```

---

These first use `Option`'s [`as_ref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.as_ref) or [`as_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.as_mut) method to produce a second `Option` that contains a reference to the value still inside the original `Option`.

Then, they use `Option`'s [`map`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.map) method, which, if the second `Option` is a `Some` value, applies [`core::slice::from_ref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/slice/fn.from_ref.html) or [`core::slice::from_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/slice/fn.from_mut.html) to the reference inside the `Some` value, changing it to a one-element slice.

Then, it consumes the second `Option` using `Option`'s [`unwrap_or_default`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.unwrap_or_default) method. If it's a `Some` value, the one-element slice from the previous step is produced. Otherwise, if it's a `None` value, the default slice is produced, [which is an empty slice](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#impl-Default).

Comment: And `as_slice()` and `as_mut_slice()` are even branchless!

Answer (score 9):

You can use the two functions: [opt_slice](https://docs.rs/ref_slice/1.2.1/ref_slice/fn.opt_slice.html) and [opt_slice_mut](https://docs.rs/ref_slice/1.2.1/ref_slice/fn.opt_slice_mut.html), provided by the crate [ref_slice](https://docs.rs/ref_slice/1.2.1/ref_slice/)

```
pub fn opt_slice<A>(opt: &Option<A>) -> &[A]
pub fn opt_slice_mut<A>(opt: &mut Option<A>) -> &mut [A]
```

Answer (score -1):

`Option` supports `IntoIterator`, so

```
let v = opt.into_iter().collect::<Vec<_>>()
```

gives you a `Vec` containing either 0 or 1 elements, which can be passed to your function because `Vec<T>` implements `Deref<T>`.